# How does SQL Server CE schema get updated in WP8 updates

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I just submitted my first WP8 application pending approval/certification. It is all built in VB.NET and SQL Server CE. I chose this because I love to build my relationships in the database.

My problem is that when I look at the update process, it describes that "When you update your app, any data in the isolated storage is preserved."

This leaves me wondering how am I going to update the database when the schema has changed, and still let the user work with the data in it?

Any idea/experience about this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394022(v=vs.105).aspx